# How to make the Visual Studio editor treat a piece of text as an atomic piece when deleting?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I am writing a Visual Studio extension. Is there a built-in way to make the visual studio editor treat a certain piece of text (or code) as a single unit? That is, you can only delete this piece of code at once, you cannot delete part of it. Also, can Visual Studio treat a piece of text as a single unit as far as moving the caret is considered? That is, if you are at the beginning of the text and you use the right arrow on the keyword, the caret will go to the end of the piece. This behavior exists with adornments that have non-zero span, however, I don't want to replace the text with an adornment in one case.

Comment: Please try to use [code snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @hellogod, I tried the built-in snippets. Once you add them, they become normal text and you can delete any character from them. This is not the behavior I am looking for. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Please refer to [Implement code snippets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-implementing-code-snippets?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT, I have looked at snippets. I cannot find anything that allows a snippet to be deleted only as an atomic unit. Can you refer me to a specific feature of snippets that allows this?